# Creating an array of years with a predefined start year until current

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

New to HAML. I want to create a dynamic Array of years.

So at the moment I have:

```
@array_of_years = [Date.today.year]
```

Which will get me an array with one item, the current year.

But what I want is:

```
@array_of_years = [2010,2011,2012,2013...Date.today.year]
```

But how?

```
I tried @array_of_years = [2010...Date.today.year]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using ranges in wrong way.

```
(2010...Date.today.year).to_a
# [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015]

(2010..Date.today.year).to_a
# [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016]
```

Also you can iterate through Range object

```
(2010...Date.today.year).each{|a| STDOUT.write "#{a} " }
# 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer works, note I can also set it up with
(2010..Date.today.year).reverse_each

So as to get it in reverse order.